# Display (All) Data from two classes on Parse.com in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I want to be able to display all of the data from two classes from Parse.com but it is not working. Every time I go to open the tableview the app crashes. Here is my code. I used the guidance from https://www.parse.com/questions/query-with-two-classes to aid me.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // This table displays items in the class
        self.parseClassName = @"rep";
        self.parseClassName = @"rep2";

        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;
        self.objectsPerPage = 100;
    }
    return self;
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    PFQuery *1query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"rep"];


    PFQuery *2query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"rep2"];


    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[1query,2query]];
            [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {


    }];


    return query;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
                        object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell to show todo item with a priority at the bottom
    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username: %@",
                                 [object objectForKey:@"username"]];

    return cell;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // Remove the row from data model
    PFObject *objectToDel = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [objectToDel deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {



        UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Item Was Deleted Successfully. Pull Down to Refresh Tab" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,  nil];
        [Alert show];



    }
     ];
}


@end
```

> ```
> >     Specwatch[668:192464] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'All sub queries of an
> > `or` query should be on the same class.'
> >     *** First throw call stack:
> >     (0x182319900 0x181987f80 0x182319848 0x1000bd8b4 0x100025c10 0x100072514 0x100071e00 0x18700c0c0 0x1870cbda8 0x1870cbc80
> > 0x1870caec8 0x1870caa6c 0x1870ca694 0x1870ca5fc 0x187007778
> > 0x184a16b2c 0x184a11738 0x184a115f8 0x184a10c94 0x184a109dc
> > 0x184a0a0cc 0x1822d0588 0x1822ce32c 0x1822ce75c 0x1821fd680
> > 0x18370c088 0x187074d90 0x10006d054 0x181d9e8b8)
> >     libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> >     (lldb)
> ```

Comment: Please paste the log after the crash and indicate on which line it occurs.   The two in a row assignment to parseClassName is effectively like just the second line.  Your queryForTable method is also unusual forming a query with OR, then further qualifying it, then running it, then returning it (all unusual).

Comment: you should scroll back to the log top, post the key info.

Comment: I posted the full report in the original question @SeanChense

Comment: I poste the full report in the original question @danh

Comment: I just need to know how to display two queries for two different classes in a tableview

Comment: You won't be able to use a PFQueryTableViewController to do this, because it requires a PFQuery which can operate only on one class at a time.  The way to do it is a regular UITableViewController which calls a cloud function that makes two individual queries and merges their results.

Comment: can you give me a link or something for guidance on this. Everyone has a PFQueryUITableViewController @danh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to summarize how to go about emancipating yourself from the `PFQueryTableViewController` (and `UITableViewController` for that matter.  The world would be a slightly happier place if neither of these classes had been invented (imo)).  Create a `UIViewController` subclass called ViewController.

In IB, add a `UIViewController` (setting its class to ViewController), give it a `UITableView` constrained to the edges of the view.  Hook up the datasource, delegate and an outlet called tableView.  Add a prototype cell.  For now, just use a standard subtitle or left detail `UITableViewCell`.  Give the cell an identifier of `@"cell"`.

```
// viewcontroller.m
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *objects;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"getTwoClasses" withParameters:nil block:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        self.objects = objects;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.objects.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    PFObject *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectId];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [object parseClassName];
    return cell;
}
```

That very simple implementation should be all that's needed on the client.  On the server, we just need a cloud function called "getTwoClasses" to get objects from two classes (rep and rep2).

Deploy this function to do that...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getTwoClasses", function(request, response) {
    var reps;
    var user = request.user;
    var repQuery = new Parse.Query("rep");
    repQuery.equalTo("user", user);
    query.find().then(function(result) {
        reps = result;
        var rep2Query = new Parse.Query("rep2");
        rep2Query.equalTo("user", user);
        return rep2Query.find();
    }).then(function(result) {
        response.success(reps.concat(result));
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! there are two syntax errors that were throwing me off and that was placing a comma between "user" and user in the repQuery.equalTo  functions

Comment: Oops.  Sorry.  Edited.

Comment: If you feel its a correct answer, it's customary to mark it correct.

Comment: I was going to do that! I just don't have access to edit it and I was waiting for you to switch that! Thank you so much @danh